# How can I automatically run a terminal command on every startup?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gnome, command

I have a small audio problem on my Ubuntu install that can be fixed by running a command on the terminal (which does not require root privileges):

```bash
pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink   device=hw:0,0 &&
pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
```

The only issue is that I have to do this after every reboot. How can I automatize this task? Please keep in mind I'm on Wayland/Gnome 42.

Answer (score 1):

- You can use systemd, e.g. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd/User#Writing_user_units
- For Gnome you could use this: https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/autostart-programs-on-gnome-shell/

Comment: Please don't edit answers if you have further questions, add comments instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Artem, I'll try the second link as soon is I get home.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of solution on the internet to this question, you can see some answers [here](https://superuser.com/questions/685471/how-can-i-run-a-command-after-boot) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up).

The quick question would be something like (at least for Debian like OSs), and I'm assuming that you do NOT need to run those commands without the need of a user login in your system, schedule a `cronjob`, the process is very simple, just type in your console:

`crontab -e`

And the console will ask you about what editor you will use, I usually left the option by defualt, which in Ubuntu is nano, so just press the `Enter` key:

```
no crontab for root - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  2. /usr/bin/vim.basic
  3. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
  4. /bin/ed
```

The console will show you something like follows:
[image]

Now you just need to move to the last line and paste the following lines:

```
@reboot sleep 10 && pacmd load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 
@reboot sleep 11 && pacmd load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,0
```

> Explanation: The @reboot wildcard in the `crontab` will execute what
> follows after the OS reach certain point. I like to add a delay
> between the command to execute and that mentioned point, therefor the
> `sleep` command.

Then press `Ctrl+X`, then type the letter `y` and press `Enter` once again.

Now just test it.

---

EXTRA:
You can always check the `crontab` logs by running:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the power of SystemD automation. I would suggest just adding the commands to the .xinitrc, but since you use Wayland, I'm afraid that wont work. You can also try adding a script with the commands to /etc/rc.d (if you have one, I'm fairly certain SystemD has one but I use OpenRC so I wouldn't be sure)

Answer (score -1):

You didn't mention Ubuntu flavor/DE or if this needs to be done right at boot or can be done after you log in. If you can do it post login just add it to your session autostart. Other wise you can add it to /etc/xdg/autostart or if you've stripped your machine down .xinitrc. Other wise see Artem's suggestion.

Comment: Wayland/Gnome 42.

Comment: When I read that a bit ago it only said Wayland which made me wonder Gnome or KDE (which won't have any bearing on the question) heh.

Comment: Thank you for you answer.